# How can I edit js object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have React componentwillmount that downloads data from ExpressJS API via Axios and gives a response as JSON but Axios converts it to object.

```
[{"client_nick":"PlayTalk","connected_time_record":183710127},{"client_nick":"PlayTalk","connected_time_record":9684535}]
```

^that's an example json response

How can I loop through every record and change connected_time_record using this function:

```
rankingTwoCalcTime (seconds) {
    var seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10);
    var days = Math.floor(seconds / (3600 * 24));
    seconds -= days * 3600 * 24;
    var hrs = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    seconds -= hrs * 3600;
    var mnts = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds -= mnts * 60;
    return days + " days, " + hrs + " Hrs, " + mnts + " Minutes, " + seconds + " Seconds";
}
```

and save object?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I suggest that you use `map()`

Comment: `forEach()` is a better option than `map()`

Comment: `for` is better than `forEach()`.

Comment: @BladeMight performance sure, readability and maintainability probably not. I doubt the list will ever hit 10k for performance to matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just try looping though it.

```
for(var i = 0; i < recordList.length; i++){
    recordList[i]["connected_time_record"] = rankingTwoCalcTime(recordList[i]["connected_time_record"])
}
```

or you could use the `map` function:

```
recordList = recordList.map(elm => {
    elm["connected_time_record"] = rankingTwoCalcTime(elm["connected_time_record"])
    return elm;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the options that Evan posted. 
You can use a `for...in` loop to simplify it.

```
for(let idx in list) {
  list[idx].connected_time_record = rankingTwoCalcTime(list[idx]["connected_time_record"])
}
```